# iOS Facebook Permissions

Tags: ios, facebook, permissions

For some reason I am constantly getting a single permission of 'basic information' when authorizing my application. This is my code:

```
- (void)login {
    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"offline_access",@"publish_stream",nil];
        [facebook authorize:permissions];
    }
}
```

http://bit.ly/z1MVsk

Can anyone help me out? I'm needing post permissions and location permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,It should work

```
 - (void)login {
        if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
            NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_photos",@"user_videos",@"publish_stream",@"offline_access",@"user_checkins",@"friends_checkins",@"email",@"user_location" ,nil];
            [facebook authorize:permissions];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that "offline_access" permission is not prompted when you ask to authorize the app. All it does is just extend the expiration date to be "long-lived" than normal. So, imo, it is not really a permission to ask.

I think post permissions is already granted even you send an empty permission. I can send feeds by just using [facebook authorize:nil];. But you won't be able to use the "message" field for nil permission, (facebook will ignore it). For that you need "publish_stream" permission.

As for location permissions, you need "user_location" to do that. See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/ for list of permissions.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: How do I actually use the location field? I can't set the city, longitude, and latitude all in a single field.

Comment: @Homeschooldev Try this - http://tylerwhitedesign.com/how-to-check-in-using-the-facebook-ios-sdk-and-graph-api